# Determine the stride of a DirectX Texture2D line?

Tags: directx, directx11, sharpdx

Is there a way to determine, or preferably calculate/predict, the the stride of a line of a DirectX 11 Texture2D resource when using SharpDX?

(E.g. Can we say the stride of a line is always a power of 2?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know in which case you would like to do this,  though I have two cases in mind:

1. If you are creating a Texture2D with an initial DataRectangle, the Pitch must be set to the number of bytes per row and is theoretically equal to TextureWidth * SharpDX.DXGI.FormatHelper.SizeOfInBytes(Format.XXX), unless you are laying out your data differently in memory.
2. If your are using DeviceContext.MapSubresource, you can't determine in advance what would be the stride and you need to use the Pitch returned by the DataBox.RowPitch. The stride could be hardware dependent, depending on the layout on the GPU memory.

Comment: This is for updating the content of textures where the stride is not equivalent (due to the size) to the TextureWidth * TexelSize, so RowPitch is what I need - Thank you!